# Php Getting Undefined function unless I save the .php file everytime using a editor

Tags: php, function, undefined

This is the situation.
I have a file a.html and a file AsProcessor.php In a.html there is a submit button that causes AsProcess.php to be invoked.Within AsProcessor I call a the function printThankYou and it works the first time. It does not work subsequently unless I open the .php file in a editor and save it. Any ideas as to why this behaviour? I am using an AWS Amazon instance with Ubuntu 12.xx, PHP Version 5.4.5

**a.html**

```
<html>
   <head></head>
    <body>
      <center>
        <h1>Login</h1>
          <form action="AsProcessor.php" method="post">  
              First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
              Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>  
              <input type="text" name="functionname" value = "printThankYou">  
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>
      </center>
    </body> 
 </html>
```

**AsProcessor.php**

```
<?PHP 
  class AsProcessor 
  {    
    function AsProcessor() 
    {    }     
    function printThankYou($fname,$lname) 
    {      
       $str = "Thank you very much ". $fname . " " .$lname;
       return $str;    
    }
  }
  $asprocessor = new AsProcessor();
  $str = "";
  $func = $_POST['functionname'];
  $str = "<html> 
  <head> </head> 
  <body> 
    <center> 
      <h1>Login</h1>";
      print $str;
      switch ($func) 
      {    
         case "printThankYou":       $fname = $_POST['fname'];
         $lname = $_POST['lname'];       
         $str = $asprocessor->printThankYou($fname,$lname);
         print $str;       
         break;    
       }
       $str = "</center> </body> </html>";print $str;?>
```

Error:

```
[:error] [pid 5919:tid 139687033304832] [client 24.7.52.150:53662] PHP Fatal error:  Call o undefined method AsProcessor::printThankYou() in opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/AsProcessor.php on line 19,
```

Comment: your code having many syntax errors, example _POST should be $_POST and extra "}"

Comment: Never got resolved. Finally gave up and used another AMI.Earlier was using ami-7665ea46 which has php 5.4.5 and changed it to ami-005bc030 which has 5.5.6 and it works. If somebody is interested these are Amazon Bitnami lampstack images.